# What is the lock file we can check to make sure puppet configuration is still running

Tags: puppet

What is the lock file we can check to make sure puppet configuration is still running? can we check `/var/lib/puppet/state/agentcatalogrun.lock` file for all the OS environments like windows and linux?

I am using puppet 3.8 in windows server 2012 and I could see that the lock file is getting created. Will it vary for different windows versions?

Comment: So seems you have known the answer already.

Comment: No, I have few doubts in here.  
Will this lock file be created even for Windows, I saw this link: projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/… where it says pid files need not be created in windows. Will the .lock be created in all the windows versions? Can we rely on this .lock on all the OS versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out which agent lock file is being used by doing the following :

```
puppet agent --genconfig | grep agent_catalog_run_lockfile
```

From puppet doc:

```
agent_catalog_run_lockfile

A lock file to indicate that a puppet agent catalog run is currently in 
progress. The file contains the pid of the process that holds the lock 
on the catalog run.

Default: $statedir/agent_catalog_run.lock
```

Comment: Will this lock file be created even for Windows, I saw this link: https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/16125?_ga=1.84955929.1877913562.1445406155 where it says pid files need not be created in windows. Will the .lock be created in all the windows versions? Can we rely on this .lock on all the OS versions?

Answer (score 2):

how's the output with below command in windows?

```
puppet config print |grep lock

agent_catalog_run_lockfile = /var/lib/puppet/state/agent_catalog_run.lock
agent_disabled_lockfile = /var/lib/puppet/state/agent_disabled.lock
```

Then it should fix your concerns.

Comment: It gives the path, I will use this for now.

Comment: If you think this answer fixed your issue, then you need vote it up, if you think that's better answer, then you need accept it.